# How to set up a seperate development environment in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, development-environment

I published my first app using firebase and now I want to continue developing on this app. For that I dont want to test changes in the production firebase project so I thought about creating a new Firebase project for development. Is this a good practise?

If so, what do I need to change in my code from the published app? Only the google-services.json file from firebase?

And can this project use the same package name?

Comment: It is indeed a common practice. You should use Emulator Suite for your local development.

Comment: Thank you, do I need the Emulator Suite or can I simply use a new firebase project and use the google-services.json file?

Comment: The purpose of Emulator Suite is for development of your app and using services quickly. If you want to create a new Firebase project for development, that's fine too, but It slows the development process. Anyway, Emulator Suite doesn't support all the Firebase services so is safe to create a Firebase project for development/testing

Comment: Okay, do I only need to change the google-services.json file to get access to the new Firebase project instead of the Production Project?

Comment: I think this could be useful to you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Answer (score 0):

You may occasionally need to use the same APIs to access numerous projects, such as multiple database instances. In most circumstances, a central Firebase application object maintains all of the Firebase APIs' setup.

As part of your standard setup, this object is created. When you need to access many projects from a single application, you'll need to create a separate Firebase application object for each one. It's up to you to get these additional instances started.

As a recommendation from the last comment, here is the link on how to configure [Multiple Projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) using Firebase, furthermore here is a link of how to [Understand Firebase Projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more), that could also help with your main goal.

I found tutorials using Firebase and Flutter that could also guide you:

- [Multiple Firebase Projects](https://jsmobiledev.com/article/multiple-firebase-projects/)
- [Multiple Build Environment](https://medium.com/flutter-community/multiple-builds-environment-in-flutter-for-firebase-using-provider-and-flavor-883b1a30096d)